# Error: First row is not an array. Google Pie Chart

Tags: javascript, c#, arrays, charts, google-visualization

I am trying to use the Google Pie Chart. I am feeding the data to chart from my API call. I am using ASP.NET Page for this work. Below is the complete code of page.

```
"[{\"AuditStatusId\":2,\"Number\":5},{\"AuditStatusId\":3,\"Number\":1}, 
{\"AuditStatusId\":19,\"Number\":1},{\"AuditStatusId\":23,\"Number\":27}, 
{\"AuditStatusId\":24,\"Number\":2},{\"AuditStatusId\":27,\"Number\":1}, 
{\"AuditStatusId\":31,\"Number\":1},{\"AuditStatusId\":38,\"Number\":1}]"
```

My API is returning the Above data.

I am doing some work in my below code in the each loop to convert my data into an Array. But this is still not working.

```
[['Task', 'Hours per Day'], ['2', 5], ['3', 1], ['19', 1], ['23', 27], ['24', 2], ['27', 1], ['31', 1], ['38', 1]]
```

This above string is formatted by self, If I put this static in the **arrayToDataTable** method, it works, but if I give the variable name in the method then I get the error **"Error: First row is not an array."**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var data01 = "[['Task', 'Hours per Day']";
google.charts.load('current', { 'packages': ['corechart'] });
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {

    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'http://class.localtest.me/api/dashboard/chartdata',
        dataType: 'json',
        async: false,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: {},
        success: function (result) {
            $.each(JSON.parse(result), function (data, value) {
                data01 = data01.concat(',[\'' + value.AuditStatusId + '\',' + value.Number + ']');
            })

            data01 = data01.concat(']');

        },
        error: function (xhr, status, error) {
            alert(error);
        }
    });

    //var data = new google.visualization.DataTable([['Task', 'Hours per Day'], ['2', 5], ['3', 1], ['19', 1], ['23', 27], ['24', 2], ['27', 1], ['31', 1], ['38', 1]]);
    var arr = $.makeArray(data01);
    console.log(arr);
    var data = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(arr);


    var options = {
        title: 'My Assessments'
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart'));

    chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

looks like you're trying to build the array using a string,
just use an actual array...

```
var data01 = [['Task', 'Hours per Day']];

$.each(result, function (data, value) {
    data01.push([value.AuditStatusId.toString(), value.Number]);
})
```

that's all you need

---

see following working snippet...
(data has been hard-coded in the `fail` callback, which can be removed)

```js
var data01 = [['Task', 'Hours per Day']];
google.charts.load('current', { 'packages': ['corechart'] });
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {

    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'http://class.localtest.me/api/dashboard/chartdata',
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: {}
    }).done(function (result) {
        loadData(result);
    }).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        var result = "[{\"AuditStatusId\":2,\"Number\":5},{\"AuditStatusId\":3,\"Number\":1}, {\"AuditStatusId\":19,\"Number\":1},{\"AuditStatusId\":23,\"Number\":27}, {\"AuditStatusId\":24,\"Number\":2},{\"AuditStatusId\":27,\"Number\":1}, {\"AuditStatusId\":31,\"Number\":1},{\"AuditStatusId\":38,\"Number\":1}]";
        loadData(JSON.parse(result));
    });

    function loadData(result) {
      $.each(result, function (data, value) {
          data01.push([value.AuditStatusId.toString(), value.Number]);
      })

      var data = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(data01);
      var options = {
          title: 'My Assessments'
      };

      var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart'));
      chart.draw(data, options);
    }

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="piechart"></div>
```

notes:

1) `async: false` has been deprecated

Comment: How can I make this Async?